# Is it possible to have columns RepeatOnNewPage with SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report in SSRS 2005 that has a lot of coulmns in it. I'd like to find a way to repeat the first 4 columns on each page - essentially I want *RepeatOnNewPage* for cols instead of headers.

for instance if I have

```
C1 C2 C2 C4 D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 D7
```

I'd like it to print like so

Page1

```
C1 C2 C2 C4 D1 D2 D3 D4
```

Page2

```
C1 C2 C2 C4 D5 D6 D7 D7
```

If SSRS200 doesn't support this, but SSRS2008 does that's usefull info too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge this isn't possible with SSRS 2005.  The matrix control has the ability to allow row headers to scroll but this isn't available as a print option.

With SSRS 2008 you are able to do this with tablix control if you set the tablix to "Repeat header rows on each page".  I've tested this on a matrix formatting for the tablix and had no issues.  With a table formatted tablix the row headers aren't identified so the setting doesn't do anything.  If you add a grouping to the table you will then have row headers and the report will repeat the row headers on all necesasry pages.